# Applying squeeze theorem to a function $(-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So we were doing a question at university, where, we had to show the sequences tended to $0$ using the squeeze theorem or otherwise.
$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & n = 2m + 1 \\ \frac{-1}{n} & n = 2m \end{cases}$$
The way we tried applying the squeeze theorem is to write the function as $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and then to apply the squeeze theorem say, $$-1 \leq (-1)^n \leq 1$$
Dividing throughout by $n$, we get, $$\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \leq \frac 1 n$$
Now, clearly applying limits throughout, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{-1}{n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac 1 n$$
Which gives us, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$$
Is this an acceptable proof, someone pointed out that you couldn't write, the first statement since the function $(-1)^n$ only has two values $\{-1,1\}$ and that the middle function touches both at infinitely many points so you couldn't apply the squeeze theorem. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ ?

Comment: @Aryadeva Comment withdrawn, you are right.  **To the OP:** In my opinion, your proof is perfectly valid, **except** for the typo that Aryadeva's comment focuses on.

Comment: No problem @user2661923

Comment: @Aryadeva why $(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: If $n$ is even then $a_n=\frac{-1}{n}$  Prakhar

Comment: When $n=2$, you want $\frac{-1}{2}$ not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Aryadeva yeah my bad, that's a typo it's supposed to be the other way aroudn

Comment: "touches both at infinitely many points so you couldn't apply the squeeze theorem" - this simply is not true, your proof is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n}=0$$
By definition means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|<\epsilon\quad\quad (1)$$

Thus obviously if $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ because of the absolute value in the definition $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

That guy didn't consider that you apply the squeeze theorem only in the last two lines. Other inequalities are perfectly innocent.